# How to draw a round pie in non square figure size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a round pie in a rectangle figure. At the moment I'm using something like:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize, dpi=inch)

# plot actually
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.pie(value_list, labels=labels_list, **kwargs)

plt.savefig(plt_pathname)
plt.close()
```

If the `figsize` is not square ( eg. `[4, 4]`) then the resulting figure will be stretched, ellipsoid.
Can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `ax.set_aspect(1)` or `ax.axis('equal')`.  (Or `plt.axis('equal')`)

`ax.axis('equal')` will also set the x and y limits to be the same, as well as setting the aspect of the plot to 1. In your case, that's probably the best option.